# Disable drag and drop functionality on HTML input type="file" in Angular

Tags: html, angular

Is there any way to disable drag and drop functionality on the

```
<input #fileControl name="file" />
```

element when using Angular? 
When you drag and drop a file, the file should be opened in the new window. This is default behavior if you drop a file out of the #fileControl area. I found a lot of similar queries but most of them are related to jquery.
Any ideas?

Comment: So you want the open in new/same window functionality everywhere? (I just ask because usually its the other way around and you want that drag and drop sets the file instead of opening a window.)

Comment: Yes, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfjqqe so if you drag and drop a file on the control I don't want to see the name of the uploaded file near the control which tells that file was uploaded, it should be opened in the same window.

Comment: I only want to have an option of uploading the file when you click the button "Upload". The drag and drop functionality causes some weird issues(related to the UI framework I use) in my app and I just want to completely disable it(btw. it doesn't work in the IE11)

Comment: How about `<label for="input">upload</label>
<input id="input" type="file" style="display: none;" />`?

Comment: I think I can accept it as an answer so please post an answer under my question. I really like the simplicity of this solution :)

Comment: Great to hear it works :)  But i am just too lazy to write an answer : (